# How to crack WCF MessageLog "stream"?

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, wcf-security

A developer created a WCF web service.  It takes the username & password (in hash) of a user and let's them access the data (if they exist in our DB).  I think, by default, WCF logs every request and response.  In the message logs, I just see

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>... stream ...</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

how can I find out what's in that stream?

Note:  I just want to know if the user passed or failed (true or false) in getting through to the web service using their login credentials.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message logging is not feature for security audit. If you want to audit successful or failed authentication and if your security model is integrated with WCF security pipeline you can try to use [Service Auditing Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354516.aspx). You will get all information about authentication in your Windows log.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation which shows how to get the actual message body for non-XML messages (i.e., JSON, binary) in a WCF REST service.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-REST-Message-Inspector-c4b6790b